# how to implement a find text in a webpage in selenium webdriver ie using c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium

I tried this code but still i am having an error:

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("C:\\", options);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.marathonbet.com/en/");


        IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("window.find('Japan',0,0,0,0,0,1)");
```

so i was wondering if there is an alternative for this function

Comment: JavaScript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError) this is the error

Comment: Post the entire stack trace. You are also not navigating anywhere with your `driver`.

Comment: is there is any alternative ??? i just want to implement a search text function

Comment: Again, post the entire error. The whole thing. The whole stack trace. Not just the message. The whole thing. What are you trying to do? Why are you not finding the element that has the text Japan inside it? Why are you using Javascript? What exact information are you trying to get? You **do not need to use Javascript**.

Comment: what i am doing is automatically triggering the search function of the browser.

Comment: i want to do is search the text automatically and show the actual position of the text like in the search box of the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to search for some text present, you could implement something like this:

```
boolean isTextPresent(String text){
    return driver.getPageSource().contains(text)
}
```

Comment: how can i anchor it ? like in the search box of google chrome ?

Comment: i don't understand your question.

Comment: i want to implement the actions of the search box of browsers. for example you will find a text in a webpage then it will automatically scroll down to the position of the text

Comment: I am not sure, but for an element, you could use element.getLocation() and then javascript window.scrollTo( x, y)

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw out a different approach , try XPath;

```
    String identifierXpath = String.format("//*[contains(text(),'%s')]", searchTerm);

    By identifier = By.xpath(identifierXpath);

    List<WebElement> elementsWithText = driver.findElements(identifier);
```

This approach allows you to access the elements which actually contain that text id that is of any interest, and of course use ".size() > 0" to decide if the the text actually exists.

I would probably change the implicit wait time to be 0 seconds before the findElements and then reset afterwards, but this code should give you the idea I am trying to get across. Obviously it woudl make sense if it was in a helper method.

Please note that I am not saying this is better or more efficient than using "getPageSource()", it is just a different approach to solving the problem.

One big flaw, is that it would case sensitive! However, you could change the xpath to be case insensitive but tht woudl be a lot more complex but can be done